# How to get rid of the spaces around the wrapper

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a mobile version of my slider which is 320px, but when I open it in the developer tools and set the width to 320 I see empty spaces from the sides as well as bellow the wrapper. What am I doing wrong?

Sorry if it's a damn question, just this issue has really got me and I don't know what to do.

```css
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 1439px) {
  .logo,
  .yellow-rectangle__seven,
  .letters__letter-a--small--first,
  .letters__letter-a--small--second,
  .letters__letter-e--small,
  .letters__letter-g--small,
  .letters__letter-f--first,
  .letters__letter-f--second,
  .letters__letter-i,
  .letters__letter-n,
  .text__circle,
  .text__test,
  .text__number--3,
  .text__number--1,
  .text__big-number,
  .rectangle,
  .triangle__dark-second,
  .triangle__light-second,
  .olive-branch__pic {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #f7e611;
  }
  .visually-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip-path: inset(100%);
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .site-wrapper {
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .slider {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .slider__first-slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 236px;
    height: 184px;
    margin-bottom: -17px;
    margin-top: 88px;
    background-color: blue;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
  }
  .slider__first-slide::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f7e611;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  .slider__second-slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 318px;
    background-color: green;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .slider__second-slide::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f7e611;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  .letters__design {
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .main-nav__toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    right: 22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 14px;
    background: url('../img/burger-menu-mob.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .main-nav__toggle::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 177px;
    height: 282px;
    top: -115px;
    right: -96px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url('../img/rectangle-design.png');
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  .letters__letter-e--big {
    top: 132px;
    right: 66px;
    font-family: 'Geometria';
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .letters__letter-g--big {
    top: 210px;
    right: 128px;
    font-family: 'Geometria';
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  .letters__letter-a--big {
    top: 226px;
    left: 68px;
    font-family: 'Geometria';
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    z-index: 6;
  }
  .letters__letter-a--medium {
    top: 0px;
    left: 17px;
    font-family: 'Philosopher-Bold';
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: 70px;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__thirteen {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 17px;
    right: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-family: "Geometria";
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__thirteen::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 106px;
    height: 106px;
    bottom: -18px;
    right: -21px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url('../img/Rectangle_20.png');
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  .olive-branch::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 105px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 53px;
    z-index: 15;
    background: url('../img/olive-branch-mob.svg');
  }
  .triangle {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .triangle__light-first {
    bottom: 29px;
    left: 43px;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .triangle__dark-first {
    top: 231px;
    right: 30px;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__nav-back {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 17px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 36px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background: url('../img/left-arrow.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    z-index: 15;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .yellow-rectangle__nav-forward {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    right: 22px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 36px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    background: url('../img/right-arrow.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    z-index: 15;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .text__slogan {
    position: absolute;
    left: -23px;
    top: 245px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    font-family: 'Philosopher';
    font-size: 9px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #000000;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    z-index: 15;
  }
  .first-image {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  .second-image {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="site-wrapper">
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <button class="main-nav__toggle" type="button"><span class="visually-hidden">Открыть меню</span></button>
    </nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <svg class="logo__image" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="988" height="99" viewBox="0 0 988 99">
      <g>
       <g>
        <g>
         <text dominant-baseline="text-before-edge" style="font-kerning:normal" fill="#fff" font-family="'Philosopher','Philosopher'" font-size="140" font-style="none" font-weight="400" letter-spacing="50.4" transform="translate(-3 -30)">
          <tspan>AFFINAGE</tspan>
         </text>
        </g>
       </g>
      </g>
     </svg>
    </div>
    <section class="slider">
      <div class="slider__first-slide">
      </div>
      <div class="slider__second-slide">
      </div>
    </section>
    <div class="yellow-rectangle">
      <span class="yellow-rectangle__thirteen">13</span>
      <span class="yellow-rectangle__seven">7</span>
      <button class="yellow-rectangle__nav-back" type="button"><span class="visually-hidden">Назад</span></button>
      <button class="yellow-rectangle__nav-forward" type="button"><span class="visually-hidden">Вперед</span></button>
    </div>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-a--big">a</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-a--medium">a</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-a--small--first">a</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-a--small--second">a</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-e--big">e</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-e--small">e</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-g--big">g</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-g--small">g</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-f--first">f</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-f--second">f</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-i">i</span>
    <span class="letters__design letters__letter-n">n</span>
    <span class="text text__circle">ural 03</span>
    <span class="text text__test">тестовое задание</span>
    <span class="text text__slogan">очень хороший слоган</span>
    <span class="text text__number text__number--3">(3)</span>
    <span class="text text__number text__number--1">(1)</span>
    <span class="text text__big-number">51</span>
    <span class="rectangle"><h2 class="visually-hidden">Четырехугольник для декорации</h2></span>
    <svg class="triangle triangle__dark-first" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g>
     <g>
      <path fill="#131212" d="M23.18 23.205c-.412 0-.822-.205-1.233-.205-.411-.206-.822-.411-1.027-.617-.411-.41-.617-.822-.822-1.232-.411-.411-.616-1.027-1.027-1.644L11.47.814h-1.028L.377 24.027H23.18v-.822"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </svg>
    <svg class="triangle triangle__dark-second" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g>
     <g>
      <path fill="#131212" d="M23.18 23.205c-.412 0-.822-.205-1.233-.205-.411-.206-.822-.411-1.027-.617-.411-.41-.617-.822-.822-1.232-.411-.411-.616-1.027-1.027-1.644L11.47.814h-1.028L.377 24.027H23.18v-.822"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </svg>
    <svg class="triangle triangle__light-first" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25">
    <g>
     <g>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="50" d="M23.18 23.205c-.412 0-.822-.205-1.233-.205-.411-.206-.822-.411-1.027-.617-.411-.41-.617-.822-.822-1.232-.411-.411-.616-1.027-1.027-1.644L11.47.814v0h-1.028v0L.377 24.027v0H23.18v-.822 0"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </svg>
    <svg class="triangle triangle__light-second" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="25" viewBox="0 0 24 25">
    <g>
     <g>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="50" d="M23.18 23.205c-.412 0-.822-.205-1.233-.205-.411-.206-.822-.411-1.027-.617-.411-.41-.617-.822-.822-1.232-.411-.411-.616-1.027-1.027-1.644L11.47.814v0h-1.028v0L.377 24.027v0H23.18v-.822 0"/>
     </g>
    </g>
   </svg>
  </div>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

jsfiddle for this here: https://jsfiddle.net/ocnw1L9x/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check in the inspector which element is causing the margins to be added.

[image]

Doing this, I can see that the `<body>` tag itself has a margin of 8px, likely causing your problem.

Try adding this to your CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to do it but it takes away only 8px, leaving the rest there

Comment: Check in the inspector what else is adding a border around it. Right click -> inspector and then you should be able to hover over the HTML which shows you the dimensions of the element you hover over.

Comment: @ TemporaryName it shows me that the wrapper is 320 px wide and has right and left margins (322px each); how is that possible? But even deleting these margins (setting them to 0) doesn't help, I don't know what to do :(

Comment: Is it possible that your wrapper has overflow? If so, try overflow:hidden; in CSS to force it to hide. Maybe a child is too wide or has margins itself. Your code doesn't really work for me, the slider is empty.

Comment: basically, this is what I see: https://pastenow.ru/3901ead201fac845626415df436871dc
And I can't understand how it's possible when the width of the screen should be 320px and the width of the wrapper is 320px as well!

Comment: Alright, I see. I think you did not do anything wrong. It's a quirk which I never understood either, but you need to add a meta-tag so it shows properly on mobile devices:  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/has-viewport-meta-tag If this still doesn't fix it, tell me and I'll keep looking.